# JBoss 4.3 eap can't find war in an ear

Tags: java, deployment, jboss

I'm trying to deploy an ear to JBoss. The application.xml has entries looking like:

```
<module  id="Core_JavaModule">
  <java>APP-INF/lib/core.jar</java>
</module>

<module id="Public_WebModule">
 <web>
  <web-uri>public.war</web-uri>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
 </web>
</module>
```

The core.jar is read in OK, but when it tries to read public.war, I get:

```
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to find module file: public.war
```

I've confirmed that the war *directory* is there; it is an exploded war. Not a war file. Is JBoss looking for a war file? Or will it grok a war directory?

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine, we use exploded WARs within exploded EARs in JBoss 4.2 and it's OK.

One thing to be careful of, however, is *how* you deploy. If you have an exploded EAR and you start copying it into JBoss's deploy directory, then it's possible that JBoss's deployment scanner will pick up the EAR partway through the copy process, and it'll find an incomplete EAR. This may be what's happening to you.

To test this out, try copying the EAR into deploy when JBoss is shutdown, and then starting it up.

Failing that, please try and post a textual representation of your EAR directory structure.